# Firebase Cloud Messaging no sound

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using Firebase cloud messaging to send notification to my device.

The notification is sent, but there's no sound or vibration. The sound is enabled on Firebase console.

This is my App java file's code:

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannels();

        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.notificationLIVE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setColor(color);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_1_ID,
                    "test1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );


            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_2_ID,
                    "test2",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );


            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
}
```

I figure I need to add some code to my project? I don't know.

Comment: This behaviour is observed when the app is in closed or in the foreground?

Comment: In both cases..